# How to get snapshot older than sometime period in azure python sdk

Tags: azure

I am working with azure python APIs, I have created snapshots. My question is **Is there any azure python API to get snapshots which are older than X months**. I have already checked azure snapshot APIs but didn't get any API to get snapshot older than X months.

Comment: the snapshot means vm snapshot or other snapshot?

Comment: other snapshot, like snapshot of disks.

Comment: I cannot find it either, but you can first get all snapshots, then filter the results older then x Months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such api, and also get the feedback from [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23503#issuecomment-458119038):

> Snapshot list operation dont have that feature.
>
> You can use [Azure Resource Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureresourcegraph/resources/resources) to achieve that.
>
> For example a query like this "where type =~
>   'Microsoft.Compute/snapshots'|where properties.timeCreated <
>   now(-7d)|project name,properties.timeCreated"
>
> returns all the snapshots older than 7 days.

You can also get all the snapshots, then do a filter using condition "timeCreated > 3 months"

Comment: Thanks, i am fetching list of all snapshots and then filtering snapshots on the basis of `timecreated`.